# PowerShell: how to use PSWarranty

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find the start date one a bunch of HP machines.

this ps should be helpful but i cannot find how to pass in the csv

i am trying

```
update-warrantyinfo -CSV
```

But then do now know how to pass the file in

any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Looks like there is a CSVFilePath parameter.  Maybe try `update-warrantyinfo -CSV -CSVFilePath c:\pathtofile\file.csv`

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using the third-party [`PSWarranty`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSWarranty) module.

[Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11954025/daniel) has provided the crucial pointer:

```bash
Update-WarrantyInfo -CSV -CSVFilePath c:\path\to\your\file.csv
```

That is - somewhat unusually - `-CSV` is just a *switch* (flag-like parameter) that selects CSV input, but the actual file path must be specified via a *separate* parameter, `-CSVFilePath` (which, curiously, isn't marked as *mandatory*).

---

**How could you have discovered this information yourself?**

While the module doesn't seem to come with help, [PowerShell's help system](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help) can still provide *syntax* information:

```bash
Update-WarrantyInfo -? | oss | Select-String csv
```

<sup>Note: `Update-WarrantyInfo -?` is short for [`Get-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help)  `Update-WarrantyInfo`, and `oss` is a built-in wrapper function for [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) `-Stream`, to stream the help text line by line.</sup>

Output (relevant parts highlighted):

```
    update-warrantyinfo -CSV [-CSVFilePath <string>] [-SyncWithSource] [-MissingOnly] [-OverwriteWarranty] [-LogActions] [-LogFile <string>] [-GenerateReports]
[-ReturnWarrantyObject] [-ExcludeApple] [-ReportsLocation <string>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Another option:

```bash
# Prints details for all parameters whose names contain 'csv' (case-insensitively)
Get-Help Update-WarrantyInfo -Parameter *csv*
```

Output:

```
-CSV

    Required?                    true
    Position?                    Named
    Accept pipeline input?       false
    Parameter set name           CSV
    Aliases                      None
    Dynamic?                     false
    Accept wildcard characters?  false


-CSVFilePath <string>

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    Named
    Accept pipeline input?       false
    Parameter set name           CSV
    Aliases                      None
    Dynamic?                     false
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```